# Globally setting the separation length for _subitems_ in Beamer

Tags: beamer, spacing, itemize

How can I **globally** change the item separation length for **subitems** in Beamer? I need a command such as the below, only working.

```
\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate subbody begin}{\normalsize \itemsep=0.2mm}
```

I have already searched the forum and have seen answers addressing the topics of setting the space before/after the itemize environment as well as setting the spacing in normal itemize body (i.e. not subbody or subsubbody). I think this has not been asked before.

Note: My main concern is to set all body and subbody styles having the same font size as well as seperation. The command

```
\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate subbody begin}{\normalsize}
```

lets set the font, however, the nested items are tighter (vertically) than those of their parents.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Rather than use a beamer specific method you can just add to the standard hook for level two lists:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\@listii{\itemsep1cm }
\makeatletter

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}
\item aaa
\begin{itemize}
\item 1111
\item 222
\item 3333
\end{itemize}
\item bbb
\item ccc
\begin{itemize}
\item 1111
\item 222
\item 3333
\end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```